# Integrate takes too long without output

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to evaluate this integral but it takes too long without results.

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2), {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -W/2, W/2}]
```

and  $(W, L, z)> 0$    However, not specifying the limits gives results

```
In[411]:= Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2), x, y]

Out[411]= -(ArcTan[(x^2 + z^2 - x Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])/(y z)]/z)
```

Comment: "Parameters" are assumed to be complex by default. Use your assumptions. ``Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z)^(3/2), {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -W/2, W/2}, Assumptions -> {W, L, z} > 0]``

Comment: Note, there is a missing ``^2`` for ``z`` in my comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although @BobHanlon's solution is more generally useful, a somewhat simpler expression for your particular case can be obtained by manual substitution $z^2 \mapsto \tilde{z}$, and without the need for `ComplexExpand`.

```
Assuming[{L, W, z, zz} \[Element] PositiveReals, 
 Integrate[
    1/(x^2 + y^2 + zz)^(3/2), {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -W/2, W/2}] /. 
   zz -> z^2 // Simplify]

(* (4 ArcTan[(L W)/(2 z Sqrt[L^2 + W^2 + 4 z^2])])/z *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You know that `{L>0, W>0, z>0}`; however, you never told Mathematica. Use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to eliminate the forms containing `I`. Use [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) so that the assumptions  are available to all of the functions.

```
Assuming[{L > 0, W > 0, z > 0},
 Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2),
    {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -W/2, W/2}] //
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
  Simplify]

(* (1/z)2 (2 π + 2 ArcTan[(2 z)/(W - Sqrt[W^2 + 4 z^2])] + 
   2 ArcTan[(2 z)/(W + Sqrt[W^2 + 4 z^2])] - 
   2 ArcTan[(2 z)/(-L + W + Sqrt[L^2 + W^2 + 4 z^2])] + 
   ArcTan[L + W - Sqrt[L^2 + W^2 + 4 z^2], -2 z] - 
   ArcTan[L + W - Sqrt[L^2 + W^2 + 4 z^2], 2 z]) *)
```